# Introduce branch into git history

Tags: git

I have a repo that I would've liked to have branched a few commits again.

Let's say I have commits C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 on my master branch.

I want master to stop and C3 and C4 to start a new branch.

How would I go about making that happen? I've tried several different approaches but am not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A branch is literally just a reference to a single commit.  Everything else you think about it is personfication.  Or arboreation.  If you want master to refer to commit C3, and a branch named "dev" to refer to commit C5, perhaps the easiest thing to do is:

```
git branch dev
git reset ${HASH_OF_C3}
```

The first command creates a branch at the current HEAD (C5).  The second resets the current branch (master) to commit C3.  After these commands, your working dir will be considered dirty (the contents of all the files are at commit C5, but you currently have the master branch checkout out, and it is at C3).  You can either checkout dev (`git checkout dev`), or clean it up (`git reset --hard`).  You could also add the `--hard` option when you first did reset.  Probably want to wind up with the 'dev' branch checked out, so maybe you instead want:

```
git checkout -b dev   # Create new branch at current commit
git branch -f master ${SHA_OF_C3}  # Make master refer to C3
```

Comment: The first sentence together with the two commands at the end are the answer. The stuff inbetween... not so much (I never would use `reset` in this context, even remotely)...

Comment: There's no reason not to use `git reset` in this context.  In fact, this exact sequence is presented in the `git-reset` man page. `git branch topic/wip; git reset --hard HEAD~3; git checkout topic/wip`